# How to make RubyMine autocorrect with Rubocop on every save

Tags: ruby, ide, rubymine, rubocop

Is there a way to get Rubocop to format my code every time I save in RubyMine?  This was a feature in VSCode, which you were able to set via `"editor.formatOnSave": true,` in the settings.json.  Is there a similar "autocorrect on save" possibility for Rubymine?

Answer (score 9):

As of RubyMine 2021.3 this is now explicitly supported as a feature:

https://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2021/10/rubymine-2021-3-eap5/#run_rubocop_on_save

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately at the moment it's not possible so please add your votes to the corresponding feature requests:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-19589

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-27248

Comment: The votes paid off! As of RubyMine 2021.3 this is now explicitly supported as a feature  https://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2021/10/rubymine-2021-3-eap5/#run_rubocop_on_save